# autoconf: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` not working in `configure.ac` when using `PKG_CHECK_EXISTS`

Tags: linux, autotools, autoconf, pkg-config

I want to check whether `gmodule` exists in my custom `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

```
// configure.ac
AC_SUBST([PKG_CONFIG_PATH],"./glib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/")
PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG
PKG_CHECK_EXISTS([gmodule-2.0],[],[
    AC_MSG_ERROR(can't find gmodule in glib-2.0)
])
```

But I have the following error:

```
checking for libunwind.h... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
configure: error: can't find gmodule in glib-2.0
```

I'm 100 percent sure that gmodule-2.0.pc is in my custom path:

```
> ls ./glib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/                            
gio-2.0.pc  gio-unix-2.0.pc  glib-2.0.pc  gmodule-2.0.pc  gmodule-export-2.0.pc  gmodule-no-export-2.0.pc  gobject-2.0.pc  gthread-2.0.pc
```

And I can also use pkg-config to find `gmodule-2.0`:

```
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH="./glib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/" pkg-config gmodule-2.0 --cflags 
-pthread -I/home/xxx/fuzz/test/StochFuzz/glib/include -I/home/xxx/fuzz/test/StochFuzz/glib/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/xxx/fuzz/test/StochFuzz/glib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `PKG_CHECK_EXISTS` is obsolete.  I was able to find one very old reference to it, but it is not among the macros documented to be provided with current versions of pkg-config.  The main supported alternative is `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, so perhaps you'll find more success with that.

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong here: As a user calling a `configure` script, I expect to be able to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and have the `configure` script respect that value. You are just overwriting it. Could you elaborate a bit on why you want to use `pkg-config` to detect something you know is inside your build tree? Also... the quoting for the second argument to `AC_SUBST()` looks improper, and I am not sure that using a relative path inside any `*_PATH` variable is a good idea. And of course as always, what @JohnBollinger writes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I miss something?

It looks like you are expecting this ...

> ```
> AC_SUBST([PKG_CONFIG_PATH],"./glib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/")
> ```

... to cause `configure` to use `./glib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/` as the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` when it runs `pkg-config`.  In that case, you are at least missing that

- the purpose of `AC_SUBST()` is to create an *output variable*.  You want an output variable if you want to convey the pkg-config path to your Makefiles, but that is not directly relevant to your `configure` script.
- although `AC_SUBST` does set the value of the specified shell variable if you designate a value for it,

  1. It does not necessarily *export* that variable.
  2. The assignment does not necessarily appear in the `configure` script at a place corresponding to the macro's location in `configure.ac`.
- if you are trying to use components that are bundled with your project (and surely that's what you are doing if the wanted details are provided by pkg-config data from within your own source tree) then pkg-config is way overkill.  Just put the needed paths and flags in your `Makefile.am` file(s), or if you're not using Automake then directly in your `Makefile.in` file(s).

If you insist on doing it with pkg-config anyway, then this variation will likely induce the behavior you want from the `PKG_CHECK_EXISTS` macro:

```
# configure.ac
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=./glib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG
PKG_CHECK_EXISTS([gmodule-2.0],[],[
    AC_MSG_ERROR(can't find gmodule in glib-2.0)
])
```

If you also need to convey your custom `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to your makefiles then you can add ...

```
AC_SUBST([PKG_CONFIG_PATH])
```

... **but you shouldn't**. Notwithstanding the fact that you shouldn't be using pkg-config at all in this case (see above), when you *do* use pkg-config in an Autotools build system, the best way to use it is entirely within `configure`.  Extract the needed paths and flags there, and convey those to your makefiles via output variables.

Comment: Note that although this variation will give the behavior that the OP seems to want, it will also lead to a final result that is a completely broken package.  The user (the person or batch job that ultimately runs the configure script) must be able to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and this approach will result in a configure script that must be hand-edited to accomplish that.  It cannot be overstated enough that this is the wrong approach.

Comment: That's not so clear, @WilliamPursell.  If the script intends to use pkg-config only to access package configuration data from the specified path then there is no reason to expect any breakage from this approach.  But of course, as this answer already says, pkg-config is then the wrong tool for the job in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing some sort of superbuild, and want whatever you're configuring to use a local glib that you've already built and installed into `./glib/`, then the right way to do that is not to do anything weird in your `configure.ac`, it's to run `configure` with your custom `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH="./glib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/" ./configure ...
```

**HOWEVER**, if you're building something used shared libraries, then building it this way is going to cause you headaches since you've effectively made that local `glib/` directory tree a runtime dependency. You're going to  need to set a `RUNPATH` (aka `RPATH`) on your binary outputs, so they can actually find their libraries, and even then the runtimes will be fragile and not easily moved.

I'd feel a lot better if you were doing something like,

```bash
$ cd ~/superbuild
$ mkdir runtime
$ cd glib_src
$ ./configure --prefix=$(realpath $(pwd)/../runtime) ...
$ make
$ make install
$ cd ../mypkg_src
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(realpath $(pwd)/../runtime/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig)" \
  ./configure --prefix=$(realpath $(pwd)/../runtime) ...
$ make
$ make install
```

...that indicated you were installing your superbuild outputs all to the same place (the `runtime/` tree below the top-level `superbuild` directory), rather than (seemingly) having a different install tree for each dependency.

You'd still need a `RUNPATH` on everything built against libraries in `~/superbuild/runtime/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, but you can just set it to `$ORIGIN/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` for binaries you install into `~/superbuild/runtime/bin/`, and `$ORIGIN` for other shared libraries installed into `~/superbuild/runtime/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

Then, you'd at least be able to move the contents of `~/superbuild/runtime/` after the fact, as long as they're all kept in the same place relative to each other.

But this sort of thing shouldn't be hardcoded into a `configure.ac`. `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, at least, should always be set *outside* of `configure` — you can script the superbuild steps in a `build.sh` if you want, but don't cripple your configure script with bad, fragile assumptions.

(And better yet, don't use autotools for this. It's spectacularly ill-suited. CMake, for example, will automatically set `RUNPATH`s on binaries it generates in the *build* directory, so you don't even have to worry about any of that until install time. And its [`FetchContent` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) can make quick work of incorporating dependent packages, even autotools-based ones, into a superbuild.)